# Differentiate anchor link and mouse/bar scroll?

Tags: angular, typescript, events

I have implemented navigation bar hiding when scrolling down and showing it when scrolling up. Now I also want to use anchor linking but that registers as a page scroll and I want my navigation bar to remain visible on such an event.

```
  currPos: number = 0;
  showBar: string = "show";

  onScroll(event) {
    if(this.currPos > window.pageYOffset) {
      this.showBar = "show";
    } else {
      this.showBar = "hide";
    }
    this.currPos = window.pageYOffset;
  }
```

The [`event` variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) that is returned is huge and I cannot seem to find anything related. I guess since both are "just" scroll events there is no difference. So is there any way I can differentiate a click on a # anchor link from a regular mouse/bar scroll?

Comment: not the best way, but you could check for '#' in your link to differentiate?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(event.type === "click"){
    // do something
}else if(event.type === "scroll"){
    // do something
}
```

event object has the property type using which you can differentiate between click and scroll event